# Problems with the Clock

Tags: clock, date-and-time

The clock on my lock screen is showing the correct time but the clock in the upper right hand corner is an hour behind how can i fix this?

Comment: what kind of phone? What version of Android?

Comment: Who is your carrier? Please **edit** your question to include this information.

Comment: Could you provide the settings for Date & Time regarding "Automatic, network provided time" and "Automatic time zone"? I suspect the lockscreen ignores them, leaving the status bar clock to be incorrectly set, and the lockscreen to portray correct time.